# Should individual letters be preceded with "an"?

Tags: pronunciation, indefinite-article, euphony

I was reading a comic book and I noticed that the author used "**an A**" and "**an N**" in a particular phrase (screenshot below). While I understand the usage of "*An A*" here (*A* being a vowel and what not) and "*N*" having a pronunciation which has a sound similar to "*A*".

Since most of English alphabets have pronunciations which start with a syllable similar to one of the vowels or semi-vowels; **is it OK to prefix the letters using "An"?**

For eg. An X, or An Y.

> [image: Werewolves]

<sub>Zenescope's Grimm Fairy Tales - Werewolves: The Hunger, page #8 (Click to enlarge)</sub>

Comment: I would say that "Y" has a pronunciation starting with /wī/ (consonant) and will be prefixed by "a".

Comment: Have a read of [our blog article](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/articles-a-vs-an/) on the subject.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The *a/an* rule is based solely on pronunciation, not the actual letter that follows.

So it's…

- An eye for an eye
- An LSD drug user

But note:

- An **h**onorable death
- An **h**onest answer
- *but…* A **h**uman reaction

(don't get me started on *an hotel*)

So, yes… your example would be written out:

> … *an 'A'.*

Comment: Give me a Y; give me an E; give me an S. YES!

Comment: +1 purely for *don't get me started on **an hotel***. Though I think battle isn't really joined until we get to [an/a **historic**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/629/)

Answer (score 15):

Robert Cartaino and kiamlaluno have answered your question, but since there are only twenty-six letters, I thought I'd try to illustrate the point by typing up a pair of lists.

The following letters begin with vowel sounds:

> an A
>   an E
>   an F
>   an H
>   an I
>   an L
>   an M
>   an N
>   an O
>   an R
>   an S
>   an X

The following letters do not:

> a B
>   a C
>   a D
>   a G
>   a J
>   a K
>   a P
>   a Q
>   a T
>   a U
>   a V
>   a W
>   a Y
>   a Z

(I believe the letter H has a variant pronunciation, but I'm ignoring that in these lists.)

As you can see, "most" is inaccurate here.  Roughly half of the letters have names beginning with vowels.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that several letters have phonetic spellings listed in the dictionary, such as [ef](http://www.wordnik.com/words/ef), [kay](http://www.wordnik.com/words/kay), [wye](http://www.wordnik.com/words/wye), and [zee](http://www.wordnik.com/words/wye). When spelled out that way, I think most letters would follow the _"use_ an _before a vowel"_ rule of thumb, including "an N" ([en](http://www.wordnik.com/words/wye)) and "an H" ([aitch](http://www.wordnik.com/words/aitch)). We use the article that matches the phonetics.

Comment: @J.R. Yes, that's right.  That's why I said *"begin with a vowel sound"* and *"do not [begin with a vowel sound]"*.  Spelling is irrelevant.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call it "irrelevant" – I thought the phonetic spellings were helpful and a bit instructive in gaining a full understanding of when to use _a_ or _an_ in such cases. You could extend that – it's the same reason why we say "*a zero, a one*, but *an eight*." You and I are in hearty agreement on the main issue, I think.

Answer (score 5):

You use *an* for words starting with vowel sounds, and *a* for words starting with a consonant sound.

So, it's:

- An X (/eks/)
- A U (/juː/)
- A NASA employee (*NASA* is pronounced /ˈnæsə/)
- An FM radio (*FM* is pronounced /ef em/)

Answer (score 4):

Taking a cue from @snailplane, I thought I would spell out the names and pronunciations (in IPA) of all the letters of the English alphabet.

Letters beginning with a vowel sound, and so would preceded by *an*:

> an A, [the letter a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A), pronounced /eɪ/, beginning with the vowel /eɪ/
>   an E, [the letter e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E), pronounced /iː/, beginning with the vowel /iː/
>   an F, [the letter ef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F), pronounced /ɛf/, beginning with the vowel /ɛ/
>   an H, [the letter aitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H), pronounced /eɪtʃ/, beginning with the vowel /eɪ/
>   an I, [the letter i](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I), pronounced /aɪ/, beginning with the vowel /aɪ/
>   an L, [the letter el](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L), pronounced /ɛl/, beginning with the vowel /ɛ/
>   an M, [the letter em](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M), pronounced /ɛm/, beginning with the vowel /ɛ/
>   an N, [the letter en](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N), pronounced /ɛn/, beginning with the vowel /ɛ/
>   an O, [the letter o](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O), pronounced /oʊ/, beginning with the vowel /oʊ/
>   an R, [the letter ar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R), pronounced /ɑr/, beginning with the vowel /ɑ/
>   an S, [the letter ess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S), pronounced /ɛs/, beginning with the vowel /ɛ/
>   an X, [the letter ex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X), pronounced /ɛks/, beginning with the vowel /ɛ/

Letters beginning with a consonant sound, and so would preceded by *a*:

> a B, [the letter bee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B), pronounced /biː/, beginning with the consonant /b/
>   a C, [the letter cee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C), pronounced /siː/, beginning with the consonant /c/
>   a D, [the letter dee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D), pronounced /diː/, beginning with the consonant /d/
>   a G, [the letter gee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G), pronounced /dʒiː/, beginning with the consonant /dʒ/
>   a J, [the letter jay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J), pronounced /dʒeɪ/, beginning with the consonant /dʒ/
>   a K, [the letter kay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K), pronounced /keɪ/, beginning with the consonant /k/
>   a P, [the letter pee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P), pronounced /piː/, beginning with the consonant /p/
>   a Q, [the letter cue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q), pronounced /kjuː/, beginning with the consonant /k/
>   a T, [the letter tee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T), pronounced /tiː/, beginning with the consonant /t/
>   a U, [the letter u](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U), pronounced /juː/, beginning with the consonant /j/
>   a V, [the letter vee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V), pronounced /viː/, beginning with the consonant /v/
>   a W, [the letter double-u](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W), pronounced /ˈdʌbəljuː/, beginning with the consonant /d/
>   a Y, [the letter wye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y), pronounced /waɪ/, beginning with the consonant /w/
>   a Z, [the letter zee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z), pronounced /ziː/, beginning with the consonant /z/

Comment: `a Z, the letter zee, pronounced /ziː/` - If you're American, that is.