# a/an k-objective optimization problem

Tags: grammaticality

Which of the following is correct?

> a k-objective optimization problem
>
> an k-objective optimization problem

Comment: Use *a* before consonant sounds and *an* before vowel sounds.  *K* begins with the consonant /k/ (it's pronounced /keɪ/), so you say *a*.

Answer (score 1):

"a k-objective optimization problem" is correct because you use a before a word that starts with a consonant. "An" is seen in front of words that begin with a vowel, unless there is some time of exception to the rule.

Comment: Well, no; as stated in snailboat’s comment and the [Should individual letters be preceded with “an”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/6760/357) question, the rule is based on how the word or letter _is pronounced_. So, while “a k-objective optimization problem” is correct, it would be “_an_ n-variable problem” or “_an_ XY problem” (or “an hour”).