# "a LTS" or "an LTS"

Tags: articles

May I know which one is grammatical?

> We use a LTS (labelled transition system) to describe the semantics of
> the system.
>
> We use an LTS (labelled transition system) to describe the
> semantics of the system.

Comment: [Related](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6760/should-individual-letters-be-preceded-with-an/6765#6765): a or an before individual letters.