# Why "a user" instead of "an user"?

Tags: articles

I am getting confused while using an article *an*.
Because *an* is used while referring to vowels (a,e,i,o,u).

But today I read an article where for *user* they used *a user*.

My question is, why was *an* not used?

Could someone explain this with an example?

Comment: It's based on vowel *sounds*, not vowel *letters*.

Comment: @snailplane - exactly! This should be an answer. This is why you get 'a user', but 'an hour'.

Comment: @Stephen Welcome to ELL. It's based on sounds as snailplane suggested above. Please find more information in the link I suggested above. See also: http://english.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/articles-a-vs-an/, http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/6760/3281.

Comment: To those who are voting to close this question as a duplicate of the "an hour" question: I think this question is sufficiently distinct. For one, it's in the opposite sense. Furthermore, an English learner may not be aware that the pronunciation of "user" starts with a /j/ sound. (In fact, in some obscure legal usage, [it doesn't](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/user)!)

Comment: @snailplane Thank you for your answer.firstly you are the one answered me in comment.But It could be good if you post as an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I posted it as a comment because I voted to close, and of course it's nonsensical to both answer a question and vote to close.

Comment: @snailplane its ok.be happy :)

Comment: Because humans are nog logical

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The choice of *a* or *an* is made based on pronunciation, not spelling.  The only reason the word *an* exists is because *a* followed by another vowel is awkward to pronounce.

Since *user* is pronounced /ˈjuːzə/, starting with a consonant "y" sound, the article *a* is appropriate, and *an* is not.

Comment: Correct, but the second sentence is misleading: it may suggest to those who don't know the history that the *n* is intrusive, where in fact the form with *n* is older.

Comment: nice explanation.now I understood it clearly.Thank you:)